# How can I lazy initialize/fill an `Option` with a fallible initializer?

Tags: rust, option-type, lazy-initialization

Suppose I have a struct containing an `Option<Resource>`, where `Resource` is some type I need to work with that needs to allocate external resources (in the actual case, GPU memory) and so might fail. From within a method, I want to attempt the allocation if it hasn't been done already, but propagate or handle the error if it does fail.

If it weren't for the failure case, [`Option::get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with) would be perfect. As it is, the tidiest solution I have thought of involves an `unwrap()`, which is inelegant since it looks like a potential panic:

```rust
struct Container {
    resource: Option<Resource>,
    ...
}

impl Container {
    ...
    fn activate(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        if self.resource.is_none() {
            self.resource = Some(Resource::new()?);
        }
        let resource: &mut Resource = self.resource.as_mut().unwrap();
        // ... now do things with `resource` ...
        Ok(())
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to initialize the `Option` with less fuss than this? To be clear, I'm not *solely* looking for avoiding `unwrap()`, but also overall readability. If an alternative is much more complex and indirect, I'd rather stick with this.

---

Complete example code ([on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbcedea8561f91a798e43c85f76829d5)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Resource {}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Error;

impl Resource {
    fn new() -> Result<Self, Error> {
        Ok(Resource {})
    }

    fn write(&mut self) {}
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container {
    resource: Option<Resource>,
}

impl Container {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { resource: None }
    }

    fn activate(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        if self.resource.is_none() {
            self.resource = Some(Resource::new()?);
        }
        self.resource.as_mut().unwrap().write();
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    Container::new().activate();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, [`get_or_insert_with()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with) but returning `Result<&mut T, E>` is what you could use to simplify your code. However, as you already discovered [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) doesn't have a e.g. `try_get_or_insert_with()` method.

Other workarounds would be similarly *verbose*. However, you could use a `match` and [`get_or_insert()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert), to avoid the [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) like this:

```rust
fn activate(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let res = match &mut self.resource {
        Some(res) => res,
        None => self.resource.get_or_insert(Resource::new()?),
    };
    res.write();

    Ok(())
}
```

If this is used frequently, then you could also define your own `try_get_or_insert_with()` trait method, and implement it for [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html).

```rust
trait TryGetOrInsert<T> {
    fn try_get_or_insert_with<E, F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<&mut T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>;
}

impl<T> TryGetOrInsert<T> for Option<T> {
    fn try_get_or_insert_with<E, F>(&mut self, f: F) -> Result<&mut T, E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>,
    {
        match self {
            Some(value) => Ok(value),
            None => Ok(self.get_or_insert(f()?)),
        }
    }
}
```

Then now you can simplify your `activate()` method, to the following:

```rust
fn activate(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let res = self.resource.try_get_or_insert_with(|| Resource::new())?;
    res.write();

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'll be adding this much code until the use case comes up more than once, but I like the trick of using `self.get_or_insert(value)` to handle the move and borrow!

Comment: @KevinReid I updated the answer, to show another variation using a `match` and `get_or_insert`

Comment: Why do you use `get_or_insert` in this case vs. straight `insert` (which also returns a ref to the inner value)?

Comment: @harmic `insert` wasn't stabilized when this answer was written

Comment: @vallentin would you edit your answer to use `.insert()` instead?

Comment: You can just use `get_or_insert_with()`, no need for the wrapping with a `match`.

Comment: @JanKalfus can you elaborate? the whole problem seems to be that you can't

Comment: My bad, I didn’t read it properly, sorry.